# How to always open documents in a document library in a new tab for Sharpoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, document-library, jquery

How do i tell Sharepoint to always open documents(mostly .pdf and .docx/.doc)in a new tab when they are saved in a document library?

This has been disgussed in another [questinon](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116769/opening-a-document-in-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library-in-a-new-tab-using-cod) before.

I tired to add the code just before the "body" tag ends like this:

```
<script src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> 
$(document).ready(
function ()
{
  // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
  // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
  // is expanded
  setInterval(
    function ()
    {
      $("a[onclick*='return DispEx'][target!='_blank']")
        .attr("target", "_blank")
        .removeAttr("onclick");

      // document type icons
      $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
        .click(function (e)
        {
          window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        })
        .each(function ()
        {
          $(this).attr(
          "documentUrl",
          $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
            .split("=")[1]
            .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
            .split(";")[0])
          );
          this.onclick = null;
        });
    },
    500
  );
}
);
</script>
```

But nothing changes. Does anyone know what the problem is or a different solution?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 or 2010?

Comment: 2013 Foundation.. Sorry.. Forgot to point that out.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript error? Are you sure JQuery is correctly loaded? Do you see in the dev tools (F12) if the .click function is called?

Comment: There aren't any JavaScript errors. Actually.. Im not cause i've never worked with JQuery before. And nope... The .click function isn't called...

Comment: If it is possible, then follow my answer. It's better than you are trying to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you requirement correctly, then try to accomplish it using JSLink rather than using Content Editor Web Part. Following code snippet helped me to open document in a new tab whenever I click on the file name.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      // OnPreRender: function(ctx) { },

      Templates: {

        //   View: function(ctx) { return "LinkFilename"; },
      //     Header: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Body: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Group: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Item: function(ctx) { return ""; },
           Fields: {
               LinkFilename: {
                   View: function(ctx) {
                     var url = ctx.CurrentItem["FileUrl"];
                     return String.format('<a href="{0}" target="_blank">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem["FileLeafRef"].substr(0, ctx.CurrentItem["FileLeafRef"].lastIndexOf('.'))); },
                   //EditForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                   //DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                   //NewForm: function(ctx) { return ""; }
               }
           },
      //     Footer: function(ctx) { return ""; }

      },

      // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },

      ListTemplateType: 101

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/sads.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

There is a [Chrome Plugin](https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar) to develop very easily. You will able to develop/test/preview in live and finally it will be deployed automatically.

Comment: Not only test :). I can say I wouldn't be able to use JSLink without Cisar.

Comment: Well.. That code works.. Kinda.. It changes the link so it opens in a new tab.. But it also changes the link to the site it is implemented. So if i open a document in "Http://Intranet/Pics/pics.aspx" It'll change every link for the documents in the document library to "Http://Intranet/Pics/pics.aspx" Also.. Cisar isn't able to save the files that i created.

Comment: I did not get properly. Please explain more about the problem

Comment: If i implement your code whenever i click on one of the documents in a Document libraray itll open a new tab, but in that new tab it wont open the document but the website same again(the website where the document library is)

Comment: See my updated code. It should be FileRef instead of FileUrl

Comment: Works great! But the Name shown in the document library is changed so it also shows the file extension so.. is there another possibility for"FileLeafRef" that wont show the file extension.. Also i still have a problem with saving the File in Cisrar... Saving simply doesnt work. Is there a Workaround for that?

Comment: See my update. file extension must be gone. Cisrar does not help to save. It's all about CSR. ask another regarding it