# Open Infopath forms in a new window from Forms Library

Tags: 2010, infopath, data-view-web-part, cewp

I have a forms library with a few Infopath forms in them. I want to make it so that clicking on the form will open it in a new window/tab. I have added a CEWP with  Javascript to give the hyperlinks the target blank attribute, but they still continue to open in the same window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#onetidDoclibViewTbl0 a').attr('target', '_blank');}
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out. There was an onclick function for the hyperlinks that was causing it to open in the same window. I followed the instructions from this post and fixed it.

[Opening a document in a SharePoint 2013 document library in a new tab (using code)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116769/opening-a-document-in-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library-in-a-new-tab-using-cod)