# Sharepoint 2010 - Open Document in a new tab, but not in online editor mode

Tags: document, sharepoint-library, download

I am trying to embed a sharepoint 2010 site into a gSite (works with https) to make the site accessible also for gSite/Chrome users. To do so, I have used the following script:

[Open Document Library documents in a new tab](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198968/open-document-library-documents-in-a-new-tab)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(
  function ()
  {
    // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
    // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
    // is expanded
    setInterval(
      function ()
      {
        $("a[onclick*='return DispEx'][target!='_blank']")
          .attr("target", "_blank")
          .removeAttr("onclick");

        // document type icons
        $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
          .click(function (e)
          {
            window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
          })
          .each(function ()
          {
            $(this).attr(
            "documentUrl",
            $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
              .split("=")[1]
              .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
              .split(";")[0])
            );
            this.onclick = null;
          });
      },
      500
    );
  }
);

</script>
```

to be able to open doc/excel/powerpoint directly from side (if script is not used, the embed sharepoint just freezes, after clicking e.g. doc or excel file from the library).

- the script works great - the embed sharepoint opens the file in a new chrome tab and redirects to IE - online sharepoint - word/excel editor, however, I would rather like to download and open the file directly in MS Word/Excel etc. (favourable action).

Is it possible to open the link in new tab and automatically download/open the file in MS word/excel, instead of online editor?

I already have changed settings to Open in the client application. Also tried to change DefaultItemOpen=1 to 0, but without any luck so far (could be because script overwrites the site properties).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding extra. removeattr - onmousedown & onclick:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(
  function ()
  {
    // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
    // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
    // is expanded
    setInterval(
      function ()
      {
        $("a[onclick*='return DispEx'][target!='_blank']")
          .attr("target", "_blank")
          .removeAttr("onclick")
      .removeAttr("onmousedown");

        // document type icons
        $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
          .click(function (e)
          {
            window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.removeAttr("onclick")
        e.removeAttr("onmousedown");

            return false;
          })
          .each(function ()
          {
            $(this).attr(
            "documentUrl",
            $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
              .split("=")[1]
              .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
              .split(";")[0])
            );
            this.onclick = null;
          });
      },
      500
    );
  }
);

</script>
```

Now works for Chrome users as well!