# Force use of client application over online editor on direct link to document

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, hyperlink, word

Related to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230046/sharepoint-2010-open-document-in-a-new-tab-but-not-in-online-editor-mode) maybe(?), but I am looking for an overall site collection solution in SP O365. I want users to be able to send a link directly to a document *but* force the doc to open in MS Word client application, not Word Online. Settings are already in place so that if a user goes to the library and clicks on a document, it opens by default in the full client application.

Answer (score 0):

By activating the feature You can force a user to open the document in the client application when clicking on the file i question. But it does not seam possible to force a user to open the file in an application by clicking a shared link.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I have this turned on.